# Scope Highlighter in DreamWeaver like NetBeans

Tags: php, html, netbeans, dreamweaver

I am migrating to use DreamWeaver from NetBeans

and in NetBeans if I click on the starting tag of `HTML` or the starting bracket of any PHP related code, it tells me where its ending the scope
[image]

But in DreamWeaver, there is no such thing I see...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If your cursor is inside the two brackets, CTRL+' or on mac CMD+' will highlight where the start and end bracket is.

Comment: Yes, thanks ,, but is there anything like NetBeans if I ust click the bracket it should highlight the ending one too

Comment: I'm not sure about that, will need to look further into that, if I find something i'll let you know! ;)